# Rails db:migrate aborting...not sure why or how to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-migrations

So I'm really new to Rails, and I'm getting a strange error that I don't understand. I created an Event model and I want to migrate it to my database. However, when I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace` this is what I get:

```
05:55 PM movienights: bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateEvents: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:events)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `name' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007ffa75a27660>
    Documents/Homework/College/2011-2012/Rails/RailsApps/movienights/db/migrate/20120331213639_create_events.rb:4:in `block in change'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:432:in `create_table'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:450:in `block in method_missing'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:424:in `block in say_with_time'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:424:in `say_with_time'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:444:in `method_missing'
    Documents/Homework/College/2011-2012/Rails/RailsApps/movienights/db/migrate/20120331213639_create_events.rb:3:in `change'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `measure'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `block in migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:118:in `with_connection'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:512:in `migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:704:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:761:in `call'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:761:in `ddl_transaction'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:703:in `block in migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `each'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:684:in `migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `up'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:535:in `migrate'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

When I run `bundle exec rake`, I get:

```
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20120331213639 CreateEvents
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

My Create events migration is:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.name :string
      t.date :datetime
      t.location :string

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, I deleted the Event model using `rails destroy scaffold Event` and made it again with different properties. Could this be part of the problem?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: can we see the create events migration ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrong order on declaring attributes in the migration. It should be :

```
t.string :name
```

The same for your other attributes. Also rename the date attribute to something else, because it is a preserved key name that you should never use.

It seems that you probably run the generator like 'string:name' instead of the correct 'name:string' :)

Comment: Bahaha well that's a little embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because I used capital letters instead of minimal. String instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I thought when writing the migration that I could use "bool" instead of boolean. That is not the case. When I used the `rails g model model_name is_verified:bool` rails did not complain about the setup. But when I went and ran the migration it raised this error. I just changed it in the migration file to `t.boolean` and it worked without issue.